# How many people does the $n$th person know?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

> Arrange $N$ different people in a row. For each $k$ from $1$ to $N$,
>   define $P(k)$ to be the $k$th person in that row.
>
> Then $P(k)$ ($k$ is from $1$ to $N-1$) knows exactly $k$ people
>   excluding himself. Then, how many people does $P(N)$ know?

Can't get any clue...

Comment: P(N) is expressed as a function of N.

Comment: In the original post we were asked about $P(N)$, not $P(n)$

Comment: Your question is not clear.  It sounds like you are trying to say (taking $k=3$ for example) that every third person knows exactly three people.  The third person also satisfies $P(1)$.  Does that mean he knows one more person for a total of four?  He can't know exactly one and exactly three.

Comment: @Ross Millikan P(1) is just a first person. It is not a mathematical statement

Comment: So you mean $P(k)$ is *the* $k$th person in the row.

Answer (score 5):

HINT: Clearly $P(N-1)$ knows everyone else. $P(1)$ knows only one person, so that person must be $P(N-1)$. $P(N-2)$ knows $N-2$ people, and they don’t include $P(1)$ (who knows only $P(N-1)$) or $P(N-2)$, so $P(N-2)$ knows everyone else except $P(1)$. This means that $P(N-1)$ and $P(N-2)$ are the only $2$ people whom $P(2)$ knows. Continue reasoning in this fashion: $P(N-3)$ does not know $P(1)$ or $P(2)$ (or himself) but does know $N-3$ people, so he must know everyone except $P(1)$ and $P(2)$.

Notice that we’re working through the people from both ends; all of the high-numbered people know $P(N)$, and none of the low-numbered people knows $P(N)$. Work out where the high and low numbers meet in the middle to determine how many people know $P(N)$.